# Generate regex to match with the url

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string want those product hubs vendor matched properly with their respective position and digit between them must digit but.digits can vary in numbers.

```
pattern: /products/8236/hubs/1/vendor
url="https://d3skctyxg9sfpd.cloudfront.net/sadassdsad/products/8236/hubs/1/vendor"
    this.tests = "products/8236/hubs/1/vendor"; 
    var fields = this.tests.split('_qa_current');
    console.log(fields, "fielding values fetched");
    /products/.test(fields);
    console.log(/products/.test(this.tests), "url getting");
    /^products\[0-9]\\hubs\[0-9]\\vendors$/.test(fields[1]);
```

Comment: Show us what you've tried :)

Comment: this.tests = "https://d3skctyxg9sfpd.cloudfront.net/milkbasket_qa_current/products/8236/hubs/1/vendor";
    var fields = this.tests.split('_qa_current');
    console.log(fields, "fielding values fetched");
    /products/.test(fields)
    console.log(/products/.test(this.tests), "url getting");
    /^products\\[0-9]\\hubs\\[0-9]\\vendors$/.test(fields[1])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be your regex

```
^\/products\/\d+\/hubs\/\d+\/vendor$
```

The slashes are not escaped correctly in your regex.

Code

```
this.tests = "https://d3skctyxg9sfpd.cloudfront.net/milkbasket_qa_current/products/8236/hubs/1/vendor"; 
var fields = this.tests.split('_qa_current');
console.log(fields, "fielding values fetched");
/products/.test(fields);
console.log(/products/.test(this.tests), "url getting");
/^\/products\/\d+\/hubs\/\d+\/vendor$/.test(fields[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex: `/-\/products\/\d+\/hubs\/\d+\/vendor/g`

You can replace the digit with the `\d+` meaning there can be one or more numbers in this place.

Here's the website to try the pattern and see for yourself: https://regexr.com/.
There are also explanations on the bottom of the screen to help you understand better what the rules do.